# Difference between Features and Samples in sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

My goal is to scale a numpy array so that all numbers are between 0 and 1. In sklearn.preprocessing.scale() the documentation states:

```
axis : int (0 by default)

axis used to compute the means and standard deviations along. If 0,
independently standardize each feature, otherwise (if 1) standardize each sample.
```

My question is, what is the difference between standardizing each feature and each sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you are trying to model house prices. Then, as your training data, you might have three houses and consider their areas and number of rooms. In this case, the "area" and "number of rooms" would be your features, and in the language of `sklearn`, each of the three houses would be a sample. The data would be an `np.ndarray` of shape `(2, 3)`, and you have two axes along which you could normalize your data (and a third, in this case less natural, option to normalize across the entire `np.ndarray`). What makes more sense will depend on the setup, but as long as you are dealing with numerical data for which the only sensible things to compare are, say, the areas of the three houses, then the features are the ones you want to normalize (across the samples).

One thing that's worth noting, though, is that the terminology "sample" can be rather confusing. Indeed, when talking about [samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics)) it is customary to talk about multiple points obtained from the population of interest, so that in the example above, you have a single sample of size 3. According to the documentation you provide, this is not the terminology used by `sklearn` though.

Comment: Thank you. If I were wanting to scale an array of dimension >2, what sort of function would I use?

Comment: The scaling boils down to `(a - a.mean(axis))/a.std(axis)`. If you want to scale along multiple axes at once, provide a tuple for `axis`. For example, if `a = np.random.random((5, 6, 7))`, then an `axis` of `(0, 1)` would normalize along the first two axes. That is, `b = (a - a.mean((0, 1))/a.std((0, 1))` would have the property that `b[:, :, i].std()` is close to 1 for any `i`, and `b[:, :, i].mean()` is close to 0 for any `i`.

Comment: One difference between the approach in the comment above and `preprocessing.scale` is what happens when the data has no (sample) variance for a given feature. Then, the approach above leaves you with a division by zero while `preprocessing.scale` zeros out the variable. Of course, a constant explanatory variable possesses little usefulness for modelling, so in that case, you might actually want the calculation to blow up.

Comment: Finally, note that reading the [source code for `preprocessing.scale`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ed5e127b/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L79) is short enough that going through it might be instructive.